# Mysql&php guidance wanted :)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP and Mysql and i came up with a little sample project. In this project i can register an Invoice, i can add some items to it and at last but not least i can move those items into the correct store's storage. As far as i see now when i want to move the `invoice_items` to the `storage` table i have to make a query at every item to check the item is exists or not in that store and then UPDATE that row's quantity record or insert a new row.

This isn't seems to me a good solution. Isn't there any way that i could solve this with a single mysql query? And is it the proper db infrastructure for this task if not how could i improve it?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

> Invoice
>
> - ID (PRIMARY KEY)
> - Invoice number
> - store_id
>
> Inovice_items
>
> - ID (PRIMARY KEY)
> - invoice_id
> - item
> - quantity
>
> Storage
>
> - ID(PRIMARY KEY)
> - Item_id
> - quantity
> - store_id
>
> Item
>
> - ID (PRIMARY KEY)
> - name
>
> Store
>
> - ID (PRIMARY KEY)
> - name

Comment: Just use compound unique keys and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to make a single query that does both functions?

Comment: @scragar thank you for your answer and how can i do compound unique keys?

Comment: how are you currently doing it? please include code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this in two queries.

1. Update the counts for those that already exists
2. Insert any new items

### Query 1:

```
UPDATE
    s
SET
    s.quantity = s.quantity + item.quantity
FROM
    Storage s
    JOIN Invoice_item item ON s.item_id = item.item_id
WHERE
    item.invoice_id = 5 -- invoice to put into storage
    AND s.ID = 3 -- store to put the invoice items into
```

### Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO
    Storage (item_id, quantity, store_id)
SELECT
    item.item_id
    ,item.quantity
    ,3 -- store to put the invoice items into
FROM
    Invoice_item item
WHERE
    item.invoice_id = 5
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Storage s
        WHERE
            s.store_id = 3
            AND s.item_id = item.item_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

> As far as i see now when i want to move the invoice_items to the storage table i have to make a query at every item to check the item is exists or not in that store and then UPDATE that row's quantity record or insert a new row.

You might alter your table structure. Currently you have already added `PRIMARY KEY` to IDs, but you can also make use of `UNIQUE`. This will make an update query fail, if the data already exists in the db. In other words by setting a column unique, the database will do the exist check for you and you don't have to write a check-if-id-already-exists-then-update-or-insert() function in PHP.

You might also use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your IDs. By doing that, the ID is incremented automatically, when you insert a new item.